# Вращение камеры вокруг обьекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вопросы по `Unity3D`, насколько я вижу довольно редкие, боюсь схлопотать много минусов, но есть вопрос.

Как реализовать вращение камеры вокруг обьекта, но при этом, что бы при перемещении обьекта, камера ехала за обьектом.

На картинке видно камеру и шар.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется CameraController и PlayerController.

Есть вращение камеры.

```
transform.RotateAround(playerGO.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 1*Time.deltaTime);
```

И передвижение самого шара

```
movement += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * cameraCtrl.SideDirection;
movement += Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * cameraCtrl.ForwardDirection;               
rigid.AddForce(movement*speed);
movement = Vector3.zero;
```

Проблема в том, что когда шар меняет позицию, камера просто вращается дальше вокруг шара, но шар может выйти за грани видимости камеры и она будет вращаться и дальше, как это исправить?

Comment: Если камера всё время крутится вокруг шара, и при передвижении шара тоже, то как шар может выйти за грани видимости камеры? Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: если шар будет двигаться на камеру, то точка, вокруг которой вертится камера будет там где шар, но уже вне поля зрения, хоть и будет вертеться вокруг. это как быть спиной к шару, но все же вертеться вокруг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делаю очень просто, размещаю в объекте шара вложенный пустой объект(наблюдатель) удаленный на расстоянии где должна находиться камера. Далее пишем контроллер который управляет положением наблюдателя относительно родительского объекта(шара). На камеру же вешаем скрипт который двигает камеру по `transform.position.Lerp`(для плавного перемещения) в точку наблюдателя и на каждом кадре разворачиваем камеру в сторону наблюдаемого объекта(шара).
Код с примером опубликую после праздников, на работе есть готовые проверенные версии.

Comment: этот способ намного легче того, что использовал я.
Я определял вектор, коротый указывал на обьект от камеры(элементарная тригонометрия) и тогда уже смещение, расстояние и угол уже подкручивал, спасибо, это то, что нужно)

Answer (score 2):

Я сейчас не дома - среды *Unity3D* под рукой нет, так что могу только предположить примерно работающий вариант (а может быть и не работающий совсем :D), но учитывая тот факт, что здесь редко отвечают по *Unity3D*, то примерный вариант, наверное, лучше, чем ничего :)

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform targetTransform; // сюда прокидываете вашего playerGO.transform
    public float smothing = 5f;

    Vector3 offsetFromPlayer = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);

    void Start()
    {
        offsetFromPlayer = transform.position - targetTransform.position;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 cameraPositionWithOffset = targetTransform.position + offsetFromPlayer;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, cameraPositionWithOffset, smothing * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.RotateAround(targetTransform.position, new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 10 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

---

По результатам тестирования отпишите только, чтобы я знал покопаться в *Unity*, когда приду домой или у вас там итак заработало, либо вы сами нашли иной способ решения :)

Comment: Немножко не то, но все равно спасибо)